# How do I center a button inside of a LinearLayout, contained by a RelativeLayout?

Tags: android

This is the code I have now. My button at the bottom is what is giving me problems. I have tried some options online but have not had any success. Knowing me it is probably some thing simple. Online examples work but do not accommodate my situating at hand.

````
```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/videoView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="false"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:background="#61414440"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Amaquiz"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="50sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:fontFamily="cursive" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center|center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:gravity="center|center_horizontal"
            android:text="Button" />

    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```
````

Comment: how do you want to center it? horizontal of screen/layout or verticle of screen/layout?

Comment: Horizontal of screen/layout.

Comment: Do you want the button to be centered on the screen?

Comment: can you post a pic like how do you want to place the button?

Comment: Yes @Jaehak Jeon  !